# How to add a right click on my Firefox extension's icon?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, contextmenu, firefox-addon-sdk, right-click

Good Day!

I've searched and searched again and I didn't find any help for this problem...

Context :
I've developed a Google Chrome extension that is very simple: send email to somebody with one click. To configure this, there is an option page on this extension to set the email address to which to send. [My Google Chrome extension is available here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/send-it-to-me/bjdcbhdinlcogieheelieecipbohhjgg?hl=en) ([English translation](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&tl=en&u=%2F%2Fchrome.google.com%2Fwebstore%2Fdetail%2Fsend-it-to-me%2Fbjdcbhdinlcogieheelieecipbohhjgg%3Fhl%3Dfr), just the text, not the install).

Users have asked me to make this extension for Firefox so I'm working on it!

I've read tutorials on cfx and it's OK. But I need to have my extension respond to a right-click on my extension's icon in the toolbar. Not on the page, on my icon.

I'm using ActionButton (or ToggleButton) to add my icon to this the toolbar but I can't find a way to add a menu on the right click (there's already the default Firefox context menu but I want to add "Options".)

If somebody has the solution it would be great!

(I'm not familiar with XUL.  So, if possible, a JavaScript only solution, please ^^ )

PS : I'm French so please excuse me for my bad English

EDIT : I've found how to set preferences in my "package.json" file but I want my own window.
And if we could "bind" the button "Options" in Add-on Manager to my own window it would be perfect!

EDIT 2 : as it's not clear for everyone I would detail here what I want for my extension :
- simple click (left click) on the icon get the current URL and send it to a mail address (OK for this)
- simple click ONLY DO THIS. This extension aims to be very very simple !
- right click on the icon shows Firefox's context-menu and I want to add "Options" here to show my options page
- Addon Manager could have a "Options" button near "Deactivate" and "Debug" and I want this option button to show my options page.
=> 2 way to see my option page : by the right click or by the addon manager and this is why I need your help !

Comment: What a pretty extension, good work

Comment: Re-reading your question, it is not clear to me what *exactly* you are wanting to accomplish.  1. Are you wanting to have the only thing that happens when the user right-clicks on your extension icon be that it brings up your options page? 2. Are you wanting to add the possibility of going to your options as a selection in the context menu that comes up when the user right-clicks on your icon? 3. Are you just wanting *some way* for the user to get to your options page from your icon? In this case, a way that is consistent with the Firefox user interface (for example, a drop-down menu).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli : thanks for the compliment

Comment: @Makyen : first, thanks for the correction in my question. Then, to answer your questions :
1. No, I don't want to override Firefox's right click
2. Yes, actually I've 5 options on the icon's context-menu. I just want to add "Options" in this menu.
3.I hope having the same UI as on Chrome, if it's not possible I would explore other solutions.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but to add items to the contextmenu that is generated after right-clicking an item in my dropdown-menu on my addon-button.  It's very surprising to see that contextmenu's are something the sdk seem to have forgotten to provide access to. I also have searched and searched and not found anything yet.

Answer (score 3):

### General UI comments

Using right-click to directly activate your function is contrary to the general UI that is used system wide.  Right-click is, system-wide (on some systems), used to open the context menu. In Firefox in the toolbar this is used to bring up the context menu for the toolbar area. This is what your users are generally going to expect to happen when they use right-click. You are probably better off either using something like shift-left-click, or letting the user define what combination is to be used to activate your function. If it is that you are attempting to add an option to the context menu, then that would normally be accessed via right-click.

*Alternatives used in other add-ons:*

- A second section to your button with a down arrow.  Clicking on the down arrow opens an expanded action or options menu.
- Use the tooltip to display an action or options menu when the mouse is hovered over your button. This is done by creating a custom tooltip by enclosing the popup within a [`<tooltip id="myTooltip"></tooltip>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/tooltip) element and referencing it in the button with `<button tooltip="myTooltip"/>` ([tooltip property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/tooltip), [tooltip attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/tooltip)).

### Using right-click

The problem appears to be that the Add-on SDK [ActionButton](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_action) has abstracted away your ability to have listeners for arbitrary events. It also does not give you access to the actual [`event object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) which is normally passed to event handlers (listeners).  Further, its [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_action#click) event appears to actually be a [`command` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/command), not a [`click` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click). One of the significant differences between a `click` and a `command` event is that the `command` event does not normally fire on a right-click.

You are going to need to gain access to the button outside of the ActionButton interface and add a listener for `click` events and then in your click event handler, you can make a choice to perform your action based on the state of `event.button` and `event.shiftKey`.

Adapting some code based on what I posted as [an answer for a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26299849/in-a-firefox-non-overlay-extension-how-to-add-text-to-a-browser-toolbar-icon/26313948#26313948), you are going to want something like (not tested with modifications):

```javascript
function loadUi(buttonId) {
    if (window === null || typeof window !== "object") {
       //If you do not already have a window reference, you need to obtain one:
       //  Add a "/" to un-comment the code appropriate for your add-on type.
       /* Add-on SDK:
       var window = require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
       //*/
       /* Overlay and bootstrap (from almost any context/scope):
       var window=Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
                            .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator)
                            .getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
       //*/
    }

    forEachCustomizableUiById(buttonId, loadIntoButton, window);
}

function forEachCustomizableUiById(buttonId ,func, myWindow) {
    let groupWidgetWrap = myWindow.CustomizableUI.getWidget(buttonId);
    groupWidgetWrap.instances.forEach(function(windowUiWidget) {
        //For each button do the load task.
        func(windowUiWidget.node);
    });
}

function loadIntoButton(buttonElement) {
    //Make whatever changes to the button you want to here.
    //You may need to save some information about the original state
    //  of the button.
    buttonElement.addEventListener("click",handleClickEvent,true);
}

function unloadUi(buttonId) {
    if (window === null || typeof window !== "object") {
       //If you do not already have a window reference, you need to obtain one:
       //  Add a "/" to un-comment the code appropriate for your add-on type.
       /* Add-on SDK:
       var window = require('sdk/window/utils').getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
       //*/
       /* Overlay and bootstrap (from almost any context/scope):
       var window=Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"]
                            .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator)
                            .getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
       //*/
    }

    forEachCustomizableUiById(buttonId, unloadFromButton, window);
}

function unloadFromButton(buttonElement) {
    //Return the button to its original state
    buttonElement.removeEventListener("click",handleClickEvent,true);
}

function handleClickEvent(event) {
    If( (event.button & 2) == 2 && event.shiftKey){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        doMyThing();
    }
}

function doMyThing() {
    //Whatever it is that you are going to do.
}
```

As should be implied by the above code, you will need to make sure to remove your listener when uninstalling/disabling your add-on.  You will also want to make sure that `loadUi()` gets called when a new window opens so that your handler is added to the new button.

### Adding to the context menu

There is no direct way to change the context menu just for your icon.  The ID for the context menu is `toolbar-context-menu`.  What you can do is add items to the context menu which are normally `hidden="true"`.  When you get the event that the right-click has happened on your icon you can change the state of `hidden` for those items you added.  Then in an event handler that is called on the the [`popuphidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popuphidden) event for the context menu (`<menupopup id="toolbar-context-menu">`) you can set the state of [`hidden="true"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/hidden) for the `<menuitem>` element(s) which you have added to the `<menupopup id="toolbar-context-menu">` in each browser window.

Something along the lines of:

```javascript
function loadIntoContextMenu(win){
    let doc = win.ownerDocument;
    let contextPopupEl = doc.getElementById("toolbar-context-menu");
    contextPopupEl.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", 
          '<menuitem label="My Item A" id="myExtensionPrefix-context-itemA"' 
        +      ' oncommand="doMyThingA();" hidden="true" />'
        + '<menuitem label="My Item B" id="myExtensionPrefix-context-itemB"'
        +      ' oncommand="doMyThingB();" hidden="true" />');
    contextPopupEl.addEventListener("popuphidden",hideMyContextMenuItems,true);
}
function unloadFromContextMenu(win){
    let doc = win.ownerDocument;
    let contextPopupEl = doc.getElementById("toolbar-context-menu");
    let itemA = doc.getElementById("myExtensionPrefix-context-itemA");
    let itemB = doc.getElementById("myExtensionPrefix-context-itemB");
    contextPopupEl.removeChild(itemA);
    contextPopupEl.removeChild(itemB);
    contextPopupEl.removeEventListener("popuphidden",hideContextMenuItems,true);
}
function setHiddenMyContextMenuItems(element,text){
    //The element is the context menu.
    //text is what you want the "hidden" attribute to be set to.
    let child = element.firstChild;
    while(child !== null){
        if(/myExtensionPrefix-context-item[AB]/.test(child.id)){
            child.setAttribute("hidden",text);
        }
        child = child.nextSibling;
    }
}
function showContextMenuItems(event){
    //The target of this event is the button for which you want to change the
    //  context menu.  We need to find the context menu element.
    let contextmenuEl = event.target.ownerDocument
                                    .getElementById("toolbar-context-menu");
    setHiddenMyContextMenuItems(contextmenuEl,"false");
}
function hideContextMenuItems(event){
    //This is called for the popuphidden event of the context menu.
    setHiddenMyContextMenuItems(event.target,"true");
}

//Change the handleClickEvent function in the code within the earlier section: 
function handleClickEvent(event) {
    If( (event.button & 2) == 2){
        //don't prevent propagation, nor the default as the context menu
        //  showing is desired.
        showContextMenuItems(event);
    }
}
```

Again, I have not tested this.  It should demonstrate one way to accomplish what you desire.

However, given that we are talking about the context-menu, it is probably better to use the [`contextmenu`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/contextmenu) event rather than the `click` event and testing for a right-click.  In which case, we would change some of the functions above to be the following:

```javascript
function loadIntoButton(buttonElement) {
    //Make whatever changes to the button you want to here.
    buttonElement.addEventListener("contextmenu",handleContextmenuEvent,true);
}

function handleContextmenuEvent(event) {
    showContextMenuItems(event);
}
```

You can obtain each open primary browser window through the use of [nsIWindowMediator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_button_action).  The following function, [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click), will run the function you pass to it once for each open window:

```javascript
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
function forEachOpenWindow(todo)  // Apply a function to all open browser windows
{
    var windows = Services.wm.getEnumerator("navigator:browser");
    while (windows.hasMoreElements()) {
      todo(windows.getNext().QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow));
    }
}
```

In the Add-on SDK:

```javascript
function forEachOpenWindow(todo)  // Apply a function to all open browser windows
    var windows = require("sdk/windows");
    for (let window of windows.browserWindows) {
      todo(windows.getNext().QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow));
    }
}
```

You can add a listener which calls `loadIntoContextMenu` for new windows with the following code (also [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click)):

```javascript
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Services.wm.addListener(WindowListener);
var WindowListener =
{
    onOpenWindow: function(xulWindow)
    {
        var window = xulWindow.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
                              .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindow);
        function onWindowLoad()
        {
            window.removeEventListener("load",onWindowLoad);
            if (window.document.documentElement.getAttribute("windowtype") == "navigator:browser"){
                loadIntoContextMenu(window);
                //It would be better to only do this for the current window, but
                //  it does not hurt to do it to all of them again.
                loadUi(buttonId);
            }
        }
        window.addEventListener("load",onWindowLoad);
    },
    onCloseWindow: function(xulWindow) { },
    onWindowTitleChange: function(xulWindow, newTitle) { }
};
```

Comment: concerning your general UI comment I've added an EDIT 2 to my question to describe what I want to do. 
Concerning your example I'm sorry but I can't implement it, I don't know where to call the "loadUI" method... (I'm very newbie at Firefox's extension and in Javascript in general).
But I've found a way to have a right click : using Widget and not Action/Toggle Button. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Annotator/Implementing_the_widget)

It's deprecated but it does the job.
I'll prefer using your solution if you want to explain me more in details. Thanks!

Comment: I have added some code which should demonstrate one method you could use to change the context menu for only your button. `loadUi` should be called in your extension startup code and any time a new browser window is opened. `unloadUi` should be called if your extension is disabled or uninstalled. It does not need to be called on normal shutdown.

Comment: I forgot the person who asked the question is not notified when answers are updated.  I have added addition code addressing when to call loadUI, and expanded some discussion.

Comment: Thanks a lot Makyen for this long code example. I will try this when I would have sufficient time to understand it!

Comment: Regarding the statement: `Using right-click to directly activate your function is contrary to the general UI that is used system wide.`  I beg to differ.  Most Fx add-ons and indeed most programs that I have used, on many operating systems, have almost always had buttons you could right click in order to get a `context menu`.  The menu changes based upon the context of where you right click.  This is implied as a general concept based upon the name.  It is only in recent years has the SDK sought to erode this common practice, for no reason, and implement UIs which are confused by multi-clicks.

Comment: This answer relies upon XUL which, while it had some life left 19 months ago, will be removed in a year or possibly less.

Comment: Effectively, Mozilla has decided that there is only ONE context, the entire browser, and thus one context menu, which includes ONLY the PAGE content area and EXCLUDES buttons and UI elements, for no reason.  It further exacerbates this flawed logic by insisting all add-on icon buttons be added to the navigation bar by default, rather than an add-on bar, which it removed.  In so doing, they create their own self-contained circular argument for a dumbed down UI with inefficient UX, and try to convince us it's an innovation.  My UX has gotten worse as a result of add-ons using this _convention_.

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented a `menu-button` that has a primary and secondary action. Although it isn't right/left click, the button has two sides:

[image: Firefox menu-button]

This allows you to associate two different actions with your button without altering the usual context menu flow of Firefox. Download the files [on GitHub](https://github.com/willlma/firefox-addon-sdk-menu-button) and store them in your `lib folder`.

Usage is similar to other button types. Include the following code in `main.js` (or any js file in the `lib` directory)

```
const { MenuButton } = require('./menu-button');
var btn = MenuButton({
  id: 'my-menu-button',
  label: 'My menu-button',
  icon: {
    "16": "./firefox-16.png",
    "32": "./firefox-32.png"
  },
  onClick: click
});
```

The `click` function will be passed the same `state` object as the `toggle` and `action` buttons, and will be passed an additional boolean argument: `isMenu`. It should be used like so

```
function click(state, isMenu) {
  if (isMenu) {
    //menu-button clicked
  } else {
    //icon clicked
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, great ! I would think to use this, it seems very simple to use and that's what I need ^^

Answer (score 1):

I tried your extension on Chrome after answering this question and see that my answer probably isn't what you're looking for, so I'll make a different suggestion (leaving the other answer up because I think it is useful for people looking for multiple actions on a single button).

One thing I would say is that (some) Chrome users know that the `Options` menu item refers to the extension and not browser options. Those users know that the menu item is there, and use it to change their extension settings. Firefox users wouldn't expect that to be the case, because the context menu actions all affect the browser, not the extension. In the same way, (some) Firefox users know that to change their extension settings, they must navigate to `about:addons` (or Tools/Addons) and click the `Preferences` button next to the extension. This is the expected route to changing your preferences. So I would argue that adding a context-menu option is very complicated and not a good solution.

Instead, if your users haven't yet set their preferences, I think you should do what you already do in Chrome: create a [`Panel`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel), associate it with your button (by using `position: button` in the panel constructor), and tell your users that they need to set their preferences by navigating to Tools/Addons. If you use the [`simple prefs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-prefs) module, a `Preferences` button will appear next to your extension and the options that you set in your `package.json` will be editable there.

Unfortunately, this is a very basic page, and won't look like the nice HTML options page you made.

Bonne chance.

Comment: Indeed your suggest is not what I was searching but your whole answer was just what I was wondering... When "porting" an extension to another browser you wouldn't do it exactly the same because of browser's "rules" and users use.
Your "double" button would make the thing I think !
By the way I have found simple-pref but this ugly settings page makes me feel bad... I found some extensions that opens another window than this ugly one and I need a way to have this button in addon manager to open my "nice" option page!
I think I will do that in another thread to not multiply questions in this one!

Comment: Yeah, it was [just asked yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26410184/how-to-show-a-preference-page-using-mozilla-add-on-sdk), but the solution isn't optimal. Feel free to upvote or mark one of these answers as the solution if you feel your question has been answered.

Comment: @willma : thanks for the link to the other question!
I'll upvote as soon as I test these solutions (I don't have time for that for the 2-3 next days...)

Answer (score 1):

Besides all the reservations in the other answers and without reusing the existing toolbar contextmenu, here is how:

```js
const utils     = require('sdk/window/utils');
const window    = utils.getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
const doc       = window.document;
const XUL_NS    = 'http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul';
const { getNodeView } = require("sdk/view/core");

let ButContext = doc.createElementNS(XUL_NS,'menupopup');
ButContext.setAttribute("id","customIDString");

menuitem = doc.createElementNS(XUL_NS,"menuitem");
menuitem.setAttribute("label", "customLabelString");
ButContext.appendChild(item);

var myBut = require("sdk/ui/button/action").ActionButton({
    id: "myButton",
    label: "Right click me!"
    // And other options
});

//Here is the context magic
getNodeView(myBut).setAttribute('context', "customIDString");

//either ; gets removed together with the button   
getNodeView(myBut).appendChild(ButContext);
//or ; the correct place but needs to be removed manually
doc.getElementById("mainPopupSet").appendChild(ButContext);
```

Comment: Won't this be a problem a year or less from now, when XUL is completely removed?

Comment: `ButContext.appendChild(item);` should be `ButContext.appendChild(menuitem);`?