# how to show a preference page using mozilla Add-on SDK?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing an extension using the Addon-SDK. I want to show a preference page in order to get some users' configuration.

[`simple-prefs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-prefs) is too simple to use as its supported data type is so limited.

In a XUL app, I can use the following

```
<em:optionsType>3</em:optionsType>
<em:optionsURL>chrome://myaddon/content/options.html</em:optionsURL>
```

to set my preference page.

I found
[the XUL migration guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/XUL_Migration_Guide#XUL_Overlays)
which says:

> This is provided only as a migration aid, and it's still a good idea to port XUL windows to HTML.

How then can I make an HTML preference page ?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in the following way:

Use [`simple-prefs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-prefs#Type-Specific_Attributes) with the preference type set to `control`. On its click event, open a page using the tab module, then use [`simple-storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-storage) to store data.

That's it!

Comment: But this still requires users to click preferences, then click your control, right? There must be a way to do what Evernote does for example, and simply show an HTML page when the user clicks the preferences button. I'd love to find a way to do that.

Comment: Yes,it can.but sdk addon. If you want to open preferences in one click, consider  Bootstrapped extensions or Overlay extensions.